# crystal report in C#, ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle10g

I have following Crystal Report:

[image]

Here data which is displayed have period 200804 to 201003 my problem is i want to sum up tax payable and credit carried forward for same TIN numbers who has paid for different quater of period (Highlighted in Report) and display the total below (in new row) the group of TIN numbers. 
Every time i encounter the group of same TIN number i want to display total in new row below the group.

Please Help me out of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group by Tin number using Group Name Fields and calculate total using Running Total Fields[image: how to insert group]

Comment: I am new to crystal report so i want answer with syntex. and what is running total field?

Comment: right click your report the you will find a field explorer click it